# Possibility of a reentrancy attack when sending funds through a libraries external function

Tags: solidity, library, reentrant-attacks

I want to know if this code is susceptible to a reentrancy attack.

I am deploying a contract A that holds a certain amount of funds. I have added a function that calls upon a linked library and I have added the OZ nonReentrant modifier. I have linked the library contract during deployment.

I know the `sendFunds()` function can't be attacked due to the modifier but can the library `sendTo()` function be attacked and drain the funds in contract A?

```
import "./LibA.sol";

contract A {
  function sendFunds(address _to, uint256 _amount) public nonReentrant {
    LibA.sendTo(_to, _amount);
}
```

The library contract...

```
library LibA {
  function sendTo(address to, uint256 amount) external{
    (bool success,) = payable(to).call{ value: amount }("");
    require(success);
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI the modifier `nonReentrant` only protects the `sendFunds` function. It doesn't protect other functions, unless they use it.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but external library functions cannot be called directly unless they are pure, you would need to use a delegate call otherwise. So can contract A be attacked with a nested delegate call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that library can't be used maliciously. Contract A is calling a function in LibA, and LibA has no functions to call outside contracts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was also thinking, suppose someone sends funds to an address of contract B with a fallback that delegate calls to the library sendTo function, wouldn't the msg.sender still be contractA in that case and would an attack be possible?

Comment: LibA is no functions to call contract A, so if contract B used LibA, it would only be to make its own transfers

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification!